# Find the domain and the area where the vector field is conservative!

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, integral-domain

So I have the following question where $$F=(x,y)/\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$ is a vector field. I have to define the domain for $F$, I have rewritten the function as $1/\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} $ multiplied with $(x,y),$ where $r^2= x^2+y^2$ and thus $x^2+y^2$ is not equal to  $1$. But is that it? If not, how do I get the domain for such a function please.
I have not started with the second part of the question yet, where i have to determine the area where $$F$$ is conservative.
Thereafter, calculate the line integral for $$\int_{\mathrm{C1}}F\, dr\, $$ where $$C1$$ is a circle with the center in origin and with radius $1/2$. 
i have calculated param $x= 1/2cost$ and $y=1/2sint$  is what I got, where $$0\le t\le 2\pi$$.

It became really complicated when I tried to solve the problem, which got me wondering if it could be related to me skipping the second part of the question?

Comment: Yes $r = 1$ is correct. But can you have $r \gt 1$?

Comment: @MathLover no because then I have the square root of a negative number. Does that mean that the domain is $D :{ (x,y)| x^2+y^2 < 1}$ ?

Comment: yes and the lower bound is $0$ given sum of square numbers.

Comment: @MathLover Can you explain why zero is the lower bound? I did not really understand.

Comment: $x^2$ or $y^2$ cannot be negative.

Comment: @MathLover makes sense :) thank you

Comment: In other words, $-1 \lt x, y \lt 1$ will be the possible values of $x, y$ in real.

Comment: @MathLover ok got it.

Comment: @MathLover Do you any idea how to determine the area where $F$ is conservative? I have tried to find any examples of this kind of question but found nothing. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: For what reason do you claim to rewrite $(x,y)/\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ as $1/\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$?

Comment: @DavidK I just meant $1/\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},$ multiplied with $(x,y)$ so that I get the x and y values separately

Comment: I think you know that the $x$ value is $x/\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. But it looked like you rewrote $F$ as a scalar function. And if you want to say something is multiplied with $(x,y)$, then say so. You wouldn't "rewrite" the function $g(x) = x (1 + \sin x)$ as $1 + \sin x,$ would you?

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{F} = \big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\big)$.

The domain for the vector field is all real values of $x,y$ where $x^2 + y^2 \lt 1$ which is all points *inside* a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin (area of $\pi$).

Now we take derivative and check whether $P_y = Q_x$ where $P$ is the $x-$component of the vector field and $Q$ is the $y-$ component.

$P_y = \displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\big) = \frac{xy}{(1-x^2-y^2)^{3/2}}$ (for $x^2+y^2 \lt 1)$

Similarly find $Q_x$ and we see $P_y = Q_x$. That tells us the vector field is conservative where $x^2+y^2 \lt 1$.

As the vector field is conservative, its line integral over any closed curve (whose all points lie in the domain defined above) will simply be zero and that is also true for the circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered at the origin.

Comment: I did get zero but I thought it was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I thought I did wrong because when I plug in the values for x and y in the vector field $\vec{F} = \big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\big)$, and do the dot product, I get the integral from 0 to $2\pi$ where  $(\big(\frac{1}{2} \cos t{\sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{2}\cos t)^2-(\frac{1}{2}\sin t)^2}})$ ,$\big(\frac{1}{2} \sin t{\sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{2}\cos t)^2-(\frac{1}{2}\sin t)^2}}))$ dot product $(\big(\frac{-1}{2} \sin t)$ ,$\big(\frac{1}{2} \cos t))$. But i end up getting numerator equal zero. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: omg, do you mean that I should write $ \big(\frac{1}{2} \cos t{\sqrt{1-(\frac {1}{4})}}, \frac{1}{2} \sin t{\sqrt{1-(\frac {1}{4})}}\big)$ instead?

Comment: Yes but  $\sqrt {1 - \frac{1}{4}}$ is in the denominator. Either way as you said the dot product is zero and hence the line integral is zero.

Comment: As you already evaluated the line integral as zero, I removed that part from the answer but the point is that once you prove it is conservative, you do not have to evaluate the line integral. You can conclude on the basis that it is closed curve in the domain where the vector field is conservative.

Comment: yes exactly is in the denominator. Ok great :)